# inline code listing runs into right margin

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am trying to typeset an inline C# code listing using the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.
However, the chunk of inline code spans a few lines, so `listings` has to insert a coupe of line breaks into my code. So far, all goes according to plan.

However, `listings` seems to get the `\textwidth` wrong, or at least it inserts line breaks too late.
In my opinion, it is better to sacrifice the justified alignment of paragraphs such that some lines are too short, than it is to have some lines spill out into the right margin.

In the example below, I'd rather see the line be broken between `<in` and `TArgument`. How can I do that?

[image: bad listings linebreak]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}

\setlength{\textwidth}{120mm}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    linewidth=\textwidth{},
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some type definition:
\lstinline$delegate TResult here.we.have.a.looooong.typename.containing.some.Calcualtion<in TArgument, out TResult>(TArgument argument)$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the code spans more than one line, you should consider using an `lstlisting` environment instead. IMO, inline code is best reserved for short stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some type definition:
\lstinline$delegate TResult here.we.have.a.looooong.typename.containing.some.Calcualtion<in TArgument, out TResult>(TArgument argument)$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.
\end{sloppypar}
```

However, I would prefer to use the option `breakatwhitespace`

Comment: Why would you prefer `breakatwhitespace=true`? Is there an inline flavor of `sloppypar` as well, i.e. one that does not start a new paragraph, and keeps my regular text nicely spaced?

Comment: It makes sense for your code to break at whitespace. And `sloppypar` can only be used for paragraphs.