# Best way to deal with overfull inline listings

Tags: spacing, listings, inline

I am typesetting inline code listings using the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package. Since I'm using C# syntax, oftentimes listings contain long words (type names/variable names). Since words in listings won't be hyphenated & broken over multiple lines, I end up with overfull lines whenever such an inline listing happens to start at the end of a line.

When I use `sloppypar` (as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162269/31877)), the entire paragraph looks terrible, as *no* word will be hyphenated & broken over two lines, and spaces may become very wide. When I don't use `sloppypar`, individual lines may run into the page's right margin and stand out; Not pretty either.

What I'd like to achieve is one of the following two, but maybe you have better suggestions:

- Hyphenate & break words in inlinelistings using a hyphen in an entirely different font. This way the inserted hyphenation will become apparent to the reader and will not interfere with the listing's syntax.
- Let only those *lines* that an inline listing is involved in be sloppy, but *not* the entire paragraph.
  I am prepared to sacrifice the neat appearance of a few lines in order to make the greater part of a paragraph look nice and tidy.

See my MWE below:
[image: tidy and sloppy]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}

\setlength{\textwidth}{120mm}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    linewidth=\textwidth{},
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
\section{Tidy, But Overfull}
By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some variable:
\lstinline$CancellationToken cancellationToken$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.

\section{Sloppy, But Not Overfull}
\begin{sloppypar}
By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some variable:
\lstinline$CancellationToken cancellationToken$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `\-` to be a discretionary line break inside the listing.

```
literate={\\\-}{}{0\discretionary{{\normalfont\LARGE -}}{}{}}
```

and use it in this way:

```
\lstinline$CancellationToken cancellation\-Token$
```

You can change `\normalfont\LARGE` to whatever you like, to emphasize the hyphen.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}

\setlength{\textwidth}{120mm}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    linewidth=\textwidth{},
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    literate={\\\-}{}{0\discretionary{{\normalfont\LARGE -}}{}{}}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Tidy, But Overfull}
By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some variable:
\lstinline$CancellationToken cancellation\-Token$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: and how should the reader know if the hyphen is part of the command sequence or not?

Comment: @Herbert This is the first possibility mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\section{sloppy, with hyphenation}
{\emergencystretch=0.5em\hyphenpenalty=-1000
By writing this sentence, we will get a feeling for the textwidth of this document.
Then we will talk about some variable:
\lstinline$CancellationToken cancellationToken$.
Now that that's out of the way, we can continue writing about other
nonsensical subjects which helps reveal the textwidth once again.\par}
```

[image]